# Locate and delete all temporary files in user directory

Tags: command-line, files, editors, rm, recursive

I use vim a lot, and my area has power failure a lot. So the resultant is I get many `*.swp` files scattered over my PC.

I want an alias of `rm` command that removes all files with either `.swp`, `~`, `.netrwhist`, `.log` or `.bak` extensions system wide *(or atleast in my home directory)*. The command should delete the files system wide/home directory even when I am on `~/Desktop`.

How can I implement so?

Comment: How about: `find ./ -name \*\~ | xargs /bin/rm`

Comment: Also, if the `~` files bug you, alias ls to `ls -B`. At least you won't see them.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg `find ./ -name \*\~ | xargs /bin/rm` does not works when I am on ~/Desktop and there is any `~` file in home directory. See my question, what I said.

Comment: Three words: [Uninterruptible power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).  I don't turn on a computer without one.

Comment: @cjm I have a UPS, with gives backup of 6-8 secs. ;)

Comment: @Santosh, then you need a better UPS.  A minimum runtime should be 5 minutes.  8 seconds doesn't even give you time to shut down the computer (as you've obviously noticed).

Comment: @Santosh: That's true: `./` refers to your current directory, the one you get with `pwd`. Change this to `~` for your home directory or whatever directory you would like. (I see you got help already, but it's good to know.) And... don't tell me to read your question, that's rude.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg OK, I thought you read my question in hurry and didn't noticed what I said carefully. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will delete all the files with a name ending in `.swp`, `~`, `.netrwhist`, `.log` or `.bak` anywhere under your home directory. No prompt, no confirmation, no recovery, the files are gone forever.

```
find ~ -type f \( -name '*.swp' -o -name '*~' -o -name '*.bak' -o -name '.netrwhist' \) -delete
```

(I purposefully omit `*.log` because it sounds dangerous, this is not a common extension for temporary files and there are plenty of non-temporary files with that name.)

If your OS isn't Linux, replace `-delete` by `-exec rm {} +`.

You should perhaps configure Vim to put its swap files in a single directory by setting the [`directory` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27directory%27):

```
set dir=~/tmp/vim-swap-files//,/var/tmp//
```

Create the directory first. The `//` at the end makes the swap file name include the directory location of the original file, so that files with the same name in different directories don't cause a crash.

You can do the same thing for backup files with the [`backupdir` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupdir%27), though it makes a lot less sense.

If you use Emacs, set [`auto-save-file-name-transforms`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files) to point every file to a single directory.

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      '("\\`.*\\'" "~/tmp/emacs-auto-save-files/\\&" t))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're targetting vim files specifically, I would recommend you use the `backupdir` variable. `:h backupdir` says:

```
'backupdir' 'bdir'      string  (default for Amiga: ".,t:",
                                 for MS-DOS and Win32: ".,c:/tmp,c:/temp"
                                 for Unix: ".,~/tmp,~/")
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        List of directories for the backup file, separated with commas.
        - The backup file will be created in the first directory in the list
          where this is possible.  The directory must exist, Vim will not
          create it for you.
        [... snip ...]
```

I use this line in my .vimrc:

`set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`

Also you need to create ~/.vim-tmp directory if it already doesn't exists, because doesn't creates that for you.

Comment: OK, that's useful. But gedit generates `*~` files.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer Deletes temporals which ends with ~

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*~" \) -delete
```

Or others like .swap etc ..

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.swp" \) -delete
```